SpringBoot how to manually create a bean, and specify internal dependency(dubbo service) as custom enhanced implementation?
Here is an example of the source code:
Service impl:
@DubboService
public class DemoServiceImpl implements DemoService {

    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

    @Override
    public String sayLove(String name) {
        return "Love " + name;
    }
}

Controller:
@RestController
public class DemoController{

    @DubboReference
    private DemoService demoService;

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public void sayHello(){
        demoService.sayHello("world");
        demoService.sayLove("you");
    }
}

Now, in the unit test, I do some enhancement to the service (e.g., mock or spy, spy in practice), and re-register the spyed service to IOC, that is: first destroy the original service, then, register the enhanced service.
Then, I hope to get the bean of Controller. However, in the controller, the dependency service is still the original implemation, not the enhanced one.
Here is the unit test demo, the demoController is @Autowired:
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ConsumerApplication.class)
public class DemoControllerTest3 {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private DemoController demoController;

    @DubboReference
    private DemoService demoService;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        // do some enhancement, like mock or spy, get the enhanced impl!
        demoService = Mockito.spy(demoService);
        doReturn("mocked sayHello").when(demoService).sayHello(any(String.class));

        //get context
        DefaultListableBeanFactory defaultListableBeanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        //destroy original bean
        defaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton("demoService");
        //register the enhanced one, with the same name
        defaultListableBeanFactory.registerSingleton("demoService", demoService);

        System.out.println("demoService in IOC: "+applicationContext.getBean("demoService"));
        System.out.println("demoService in demoController: "+demoController.demoService);
    }
}

service in IOC and in controller are different
The demoService in controller is not the enhanced one, thus, I can't get the mocked result.
I haven tried to replace the service in controller by reflection, and it does work!
However, in practice, my dependency relation may be like:
controller <-- serviceA <-- serviceB <--serviceC
And I enhance serviceC and re-register serviceC to IOC. Refelction may be troublesome, and there may be other enhanced services. So I hope not to mark them each by each.
So, I wonder: how to manually get the controller in the code, like @AutoWired, if it finds the existed dependency bean (custom enhanced) in IOC, just use, don't create a new default one.

there is already a solution for that @MockBean. It will automatically register and inject a mock into spring services that require it, in your test.  See  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/api/java/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html
